# App not getting published in all countries

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to publish a card game to google play store and every time I do I get the below e-mail app from Google Play Team. I have changed the package name and category of the app 3 times then also the same issue comes up again and again the app has no ads but it offers in-app purchase.It is simple card game which allows users to play various card games like rummy teen Patti etc.

The below is the e-mail

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> This is a notification that your app, kotshena, with package name
>   com.sel.kot, is no longer available to Google Play users in Algeria,
>   Iran, Jordan, Libya, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, Syria, Tunisia, United
>   Arab Emirates, Palestine, Yemen, or South Korea. This does not affect
>   your app's status in other countries.
>
> Policy issue: Apps that simulate gambling, or games of chance or skill
>   that are conducive to gambling are prohibited in the above locales.
>
> If you already have a rating issued by the Korean Game Rating and
>   Administrations Committee (KGRAC), you can submit it to our policy
>   support team. If you would like to apply for a rating from KGRAC,
>   please visit their website for instructions.
>
> If the remainder of your app catalog includes similar apps which
>   contain high maturity content such as sexuality, violence, drugs,
>   language, or gambling (betting) etc., please be aware that their
>   availability in the aforementioned countries may also be removed. We
>   ask that you unpublish these apps from the country or countries listed
>   above.
>
> Regards,
>
> The Google Play Team

Comment: Does your App has gambling?? For this kind of questions I think the best help you can get is from PlayStore Team themselves....

Comment: this is the reason _Apps that simulate gambling, or games of chance or skill that are conducive to gambling are prohibited in the above locales._

Comment: Yeah app allows users to play card game with each other and it is pure gambling I agree but how to make the app available in this countries any solutions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Google Play Store policies and not about programming

Answer (score 1):

The email says this:

> Apps that simulate gambling, or games of chance or skill that are conducive to gambling are prohibited in the above locales.

Your app simulates various card games.  These are clearly games of chance, and your app is "conducive to gambling" in the sense that people can bet (against each other) on the outcome.

It seems pretty clear cut to me.

But either way, Google has the right to do this kind of thing.  Note that they are doing this because if they didn't they would be at risk of (for example) having *all* access to Google Play banned in those countries by their respective governments.

Comment: Yeah app allows users to play card game with each other and it is pure gambling I agree but how to make the app available in this countries any solutions?

Comment: Simply ... you can't do it legally.